# List formula date conditional not working

Tags: list, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I have a list that takes an Open Date and adds 90 days to set a due date:

```
=[Open Date]+90
```

However, many of the Open Dates are years old. I've been asked to change it so that dates created before `May 31, 2014`, should default to `August 31, 2014`.

I asked the question in `msdn` forums, and (thanks Waqas) got:

```
=IF(([Open Date]+90)<5/31/2014,"8/31/2014",[Open Date]+90)
```

It looks right, but it's still not working. One of my Open Dates is `1/2/2009`, and it's still coming up as `4/2/2009`.

Comment: For the formula to refresh, you'll need to edit the item and save it

Comment: Thanks Eric, tried refreshing (changed the Open Date) but didn't change the Due Date.

Answer (score 1):

try this formula, hope it will work.

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(opendate+90)<2014,MONTH(opendate+90)<5,DAY(opendate+90)<31),"8/31/2014",opendate+90)
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas, getting warmer. Now some of the pre 5/31/2014 dates are showing as 8/31/2014, and others are not. EG: Open Date 1/2/2009 is coming up as 8/31/2014, but 6/12/2009 is 9/10/2009. I see the AND operator, but thought maybe it wasn't carrying through. I looked through the list, and see that all of the opendates that changed to 8/31/2014 had a 1 as the first character in the date -- anything from January, October, November, December is now 8/31, but anything from the other months wasn't recognized.